# Oracle SQL select and join table with millions of records real time

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Not even sure if possible but my query is this:

```
select * from 
    (select dh.IDFILE as idfile
          , sg.XSHCSCMIDFISCIVAIDPAESE as codaziendamittente
          , azmitt.ragionesociale as ragsocmitt
          , sg.XSHCDPRIDFISCIVAIDPAESE as codaziendadestinatario
          , azdest.ragionesociale as ragsocdest
          , dh.codcomunita as codcomunita
          , sg.xsbdtgnnumero as numerodoc
          , sg.codformatodocumento as codformatodocumento
          , sg.xsbdtgnddata as datadoc
          , sg.xshcdpridfiscivaidcodice as sgmitt
          , sg.XSHCDPRCODICEFISCALE as sgmittragsoc
          , sg.xshcscmidfiscivaidcodice as sgdest
          , sg.XSHCSCMCODICEFISCALE as sgdestragsoc
          , da.tipoack
          , da.stato as stato
          , sg.xsbdtgnddata as datainsert
          , sg.dhdatainsert as dataoraricezione
          , da.datainsert as datelastupdate
          , dh.idrs, sg.identificativosdi as sdi
          , sg.tipofile as ciclofatturazione
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dh.idfile, dh.datainsert ORDER BY da.datelastupdate desc) rn 
    from sogeidoc sg 
    join datahistoryindex dh on sg.DHIDFILE = dh.IDFILE 
                            and sg.dhdatainsert = dh.datainsert 
    join datahistoryack da on da.IDFILE = dh.IDFILE 
                            and da.datainsert = dh.datainsert 
    left join azienda azmitt on dh.codaziendamittente = azmitt.codazienda 
                            and dh.codcomunita = azmitt.codcomunita 
    left join azienda azdest on dh.codaziendadestinatario = azdest.codazienda 
                            and dh.codcomunita = azdest.codcomunita) 
where rn = 1 
and codcomunita ='AGRILL' 
order by datelastupdate desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

problem: datahistoryack is 143'889'309 records, datahistoryindex is 143'889'309 records and sogeidoc is 19'386'835 records, 
in my current java code I execute this query everytime a user make a search and I paginate each page of 100 rows (I only change the offet from 0 to number of page *100 -100). codcomunita is the only mandatory field.
Also the ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION is necessary and I cannot use a materialized view because the user should be able to find data updated in realtime.

There is any way I can solve this problem or there is no way to get a result in, at most, under 10 minutes? Right now it just stay in execution forever.

Any way to optimize this query is also welcome.
I'm not skilled in sql, I just know the basics (I made this query with the help of my tutor at work), and this was working on a much smaller database, but even my tutor said he is not able to solve this problem so I'm stuck. In any answer I will still need lot's of information on how to implement a complex solution since I'm still new to the sql world.

EDIT

```
DATAHISTORYACK  IDFILE  44040192    C2021B  C42D212B2B  0,000000022706531343006 6
DATAHISTORYACK  DATAINSERT  4756992 78760612110C1F  78770B1B060202  0   8
DATAHISTORYACK  CODCOMUNITA 17  4141423242  57494B49    0,00000000346502548460408   7
DATAHISTORYACK  DATELASTUPDATE  6566912 78760612110C20  78770B1B060202  0   8
DATAHISTORYINDEX    IDFILE  44040192    C102    C42D212C56  0,000000022706531343006 6
DATAHISTORYINDEX    DATAINSERT  4757504 7876051D0B1A17  78770B1B061201  0   8
DATAHISTORYINDEX    CODCOMUNITA 17  4141423242  57494B49    0,0000000113196238651992    7
DATAHISTORYINDEX    DATELASTUPDATE  2656768 7876051D0B1A17  78770B1B061201  0   8
SOGEIDOC    CODCOMUNITA 19  4141423242  617574696E76    0,0000000257141209969735    7
SOGEIDOC    DATELASTUPDATE  1359360 77B40101010101  78770B1B062E1E  0,000001    8
```

Comment: Does the tables have the proper Indexes created?

Comment: Two things I would do : 

1) I would make sure the indexes are created properly.
2) Try using materialized views.

Comment: @DavidD'Lima Like I said in the question I cannot use materialized views, result should be in real-time. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Tony I think yes, but I'm not sure since I have not created any table on this database. I will try to check on this.

Comment: This requirement sounds like BIG DATA

Comment: @Tony Yes, you're right (at least that what my tutor said). But I'm not sure I can do anything about that (I know nothing about Big Data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide a good answer I would need:

- Histogram data for dh.codcomunita, dh.idfile, dh.datainsert, da.datelastupdate
- Estimated result without filter of the query without fetch filters
- Execution plan of query

It's a big difference if you search for the last changes of 1'000 files or 1 million. 
Isn't it possible to filter on table sogeidoc first. Some information like codcomunita should be in there.

Comment: I will try to answer:- Not sure how to get the histogram data I'm sorry. - Even simple select count(0) from datahistoryack, select count(0) from datahistoryindex and select count(0) from sogeidoc require 5-4-3 minutes.  I will try to apply some filter first. Thank you.

Comment: select  table_name, column_name,num_rows,blocks,avg_row_len,sample_size,last_analyzed from user_tables where table_name in ('DATAHISTORYINDEX','SOGEIDOC','DATAHISTORYACK','AZIENDA');

select table_name, column_name, num_distinct,low_value,high_value,density,avg_col_len from USER_TAB_COL_STATISTICS 
where table_name in ('DATAHISTORYINDEX','SOGEIDOC','DATAHISTORYACK') 
and column_Name in('CODCOMUNITA','IDFILE','DATAINSERT','DATELASTUPDATE');

Comment: the first query give me "invalid identifier" error, the second query give me an empty result.

Comment: Try all_* instead of user_*

Comment: I will update my question with the result of the second query

Comment: So you have 17 different entries for CODCOMUNITA. This is not very selective. DHIDFILE  from SOGEIDOC is missing. But will be around 20 million probably. What I would do is to select all changes since a certain date (1week) and then apply the filters. There should be enough data in the result to do the further work.

Comment: Ok I was able to go under 1 minute with date. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an index after all joining tables with huge number of records already in each table with overhead query manipulation as via rownumber and partition by takes time. So, all you could do for now is an index on the columns which are unique and which are especially used in your join conditions.

Comment: Tables already contains index on colums that I use in my join conditions. Thank you anyway

Comment: You need to partition your database

Comment: Can you explain how can I partition the database? I'm not sure if I have to ask the database team to do something like that (I cannot modify the database directly, I can only make query to select, insert, update,delete data).

Comment: for what I read on wikipedia I cannot do partition of the database (not just that, the db team will not do a partition of the database). If it's not possible to optimize the query I will not be able to solve my problem.